# No me funciona el método jquery $("nombreEtiqueta").append(miVariable)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, dom

Necesito por favor que alguien me ayude.

Mi página *HTML* recoge una variable  en la que su contenido es código html, pero al usar `$("nombreEtiqueta").append(mivariable)` me lo muestra como texto.
El còdigo es el siguiente:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    mivar = "{{CalendarioHtml}}";
    $("#ContenedorCitas").append(mivar);
    $("#ContenedorCitas").html(String(mivar));
    }); 
</script>
```

La variable {{CalendarioHtml}} contiene código html variable. Si cojo el contenido de esta varible, que me muestra en pantalla erróneamente, y la pego en un html, me lo pinta bien, por lo que el código html que contiene la variable es correcto.
Debe de ser algún tema de conversión pero ni convirtiendo a String funciona

Comment: si es un id has de añadir `#` y si es una clase `.` ej. `$("#idEtiqueta")`

Comment: <script>   
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
        mivar = "{{CalendarioHtml}}";
        $("#ContenedorCitas").append(mivar);
        $("#ContenedorCitas").html(String(mivar));
        }); 
</script>              El contenido de mivar o {{CalendarioHtml}}" es código html pero me muestra solo el código

Comment: Puedes pulsar [edit] para añadir el código a la pregunta y así mejorarla, también te recomiendo [tour] para que entiendas mejor el sitio, estoy mirando, parece un problema de sincronías

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez lo que necesites es usar .html()

```
$("nombreEtiqueta").append(mivariable)

$("nombreEtiqueta").html(mivariable)
```

dale un vistazo al ejemplo de [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_set)

Comment: He probado  ambas formas y no funciona. . este es el código                    <script>   
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
        mivar = "{{CalendarioHtml}}";
        $("#ContenedorCitas").append(mivar);
        $("#ContenedorCitas").html(String(mivar));
        }); 
</script>